# Word Macro - Get Original Size Without Resizing

Tags: vba, ms-word, resize

I want a macro that checks the size of embedded OLEObjects against their original dimensions. When you try to get scale properties of Shapes or InlineShapes then you get meaningless numbers (e.g. 0 ) so the workaround I ended up at is to check their size, then resize to 100% of original size, then check that size and compare. Is there a better way?

```
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                sW = shp.Width
                sH = shp.Height
                shp.ScaleWidth 1#, msoTrue
                shp.ScaleHeight 1#, msoTrue
                sW = sW / shp.Width
                sH = sH / shp.Height
                shp.ScaleWidth sW, msoTrue
                shp.ScaleHeight sH, msoTrue
        End If
    Next
    For Each ishp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If ishp.Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                sW = ishp.Width
                sH = ishp.Height
                ishp.ScaleWidth = 100
                ishp.ScaleHeight = 100
                sW = sW / ishp.Width
                sH = sH / ishp.Height
                ishp.ScaleWidth = sW * 100
                ishp.ScaleHeight = sH * 100
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Not to my knowledge. There's not a Property that gives you the original sizing, so all you can do is resize it to 100% as you are.

Comment: I don't know if it blows my mind or pisses me off that you can right click properties and Word pops up a nice little box with the original dimensions and current scale but you can't get at those numbers without resizing it!

Comment: The value of ScaleHeight and ScaleWidth will be accurate as long as no one has cleared the "Relative to original picture size" checkbox and then manipulated the image size. But with that said, any object that is larger than the area between the page margins is going to be automatically resized by Word when its inserted.